# Install Eclipse RCP executable without admin rights

Tags: eclipse, installation, admin-rights

I have created Eclipse RCP installer using a third party tool . While installing it always asks for admin rights. Is there any way in Eclipse product configuration to avoid this.

Please help

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: What third party tool? The question seems more related to that than Eclipse.